# Is the conductor oscillating because of the presence of an electric field acting on it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-circuits

[image: question]

Hi, what I am wondering is that why does the conductor oscillate? I picked B because the way the answers were set sort of leads you to pick it(Its correct according to the answer sheet). But I feel that A is the answer that appeals most to my knowledge. Back to answer B, I am wondering is it oscillating because there is an electric field exerting a force on the charge?

Just listing what I know:

I know the positively charged conductor will induce negative charges/electrons to gather on the right side of P and repel the electrons at Q causing it to become positively charged on the left side.

There is an electric field formed between P and Q.

Conductor X experiences a force due to the magnetic field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the question is not itself clear yet as this can be explained on a variety of phenomenans , as charge can be induced upon those spheres due to charge shown at end of the wires, is switch is closed then flux related  changes across the conductor and thay flux will increase at first in inward direction causing anticlockwise current in conductor. Please specify the topic on which we have to answer (electrostats or electomagnetic induction). Also this setup seems like these isolated sphere are acting as a capacitor then surely the conductor will oscilate as capacitor has electric field lines from (positive to negative).The positive and negative spheres could induce some charge upon the conductor.now if the conductor were to accelrate towards the plate,surely the plate will hit either of the plate.Now to conserve the momentum the conductor will go within opposite to initial velocity. This process continues as long as the balls are charges.

Hope you understand you can also check this phenomenan on walter lewin youtube channel when he talks about capacitor.

Comment: What topics do I have to research to solve this. Electric fields and its impact on charges? Also, is this linked to circuits?

Comment: You should check the basic concept of electric fields and charges,it it not related to circuit. It is related to capacitor and electric field lines within a capacitor that should be enough

Comment: Thanks Kakashi.

Comment: No problem and i would be much obliged if you could tell me how was my explanation or the part you didn't understand yet

Comment: Okay I'll just say what I know and you can tell me if I'm wrong or right. There are electric field lines in the direction of Q to P. The positively charged conductor moves to the minus terminal(to P). But I'm not sure why it doesn't stick to P.    Isn't there an attractive force?

Comment: Until this point you are completely right now now if there's some attractive force does it mean the object's gonna stick, imagine you throw a ball towards ground it does bounce back and the reason behind that is conservation of linear momentum, the conductor could stick to the sphere but it would require very high force of attraction

Comment: I see, thanks!!